# T-SQL - Limit Number of Rows (ROWS OFFSET) in the output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Code:

```
DECLARE @TileNumber INT = 0
        , @RowsToReturn INT = 25 ;

;WITH [Num1] AS
    (
        SELECT  [N].[Intrgr]
        FROM    (
                    VALUES
                        ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                ) AS [N] ( [Intrgr] )
    )
    , [Num2] AS
    (
        SELECT      [Num] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [N1].[Intrgr] )
        FROM        [Num1] AS [N1]
        CROSS JOIN  [Num1] AS [N2]
    )
SELECT  * INTO #Temp1
FROM    [Num2] ;

;WITH [Num1] AS
    (
        SELECT  [N].[Intrgr]
        FROM    (
                    VALUES
                        ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                      , ( 0 )
                ) AS [N] ( [Intrgr] )
    )
    , [Num2] AS
    (
        SELECT      [Num] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [N1].[Intrgr] ) + 100
        FROM        [Num1] AS [N1]
        CROSS JOIN  [Num1] AS [N2]
    )
SELECT  * INTO #Temp2
FROM    [Num2] ;

--SELECT * FROM #Temp1 -- 49 Rows
--SELECT * FROM #Temp2 -- 16 Rows

;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT      [Num]
        FROM        #Temp1
        ORDER BY    [Num] OFFSET ( @TileNumber * @RowsToReturn ) ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowsToReturn ROWS ONLY
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      [Num]
        FROM        #Temp2
        ORDER BY    [Num] OFFSET ( @TileNumber * @RowsToReturn ) ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowsToReturn ROWS ONLY
    )
SELECT      [C].[Num]
FROM        CTE [C]
ORDER BY    [C].[Num] OFFSET ( @TileNumber * @RowsToReturn ) ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowsToReturn ROWS ONLY ;


DROP TABLE #Temp1 ;
DROP TABLE #Temp2 ;
```

Description
There're total of 65 records in this example when we UNION ALL. Real table data may vary.

Expected Result for this example
When @TileNumber is 0 (1st set of 25 records), I want Num 1-25 returned

When @tileNumber is 1 (2nd set of 25 records), I want Num 26-50 returned

When @TileNumber is 2 (3rd set of 25 records), I want Num 51-65 returned

When @TileNumber is anything else, nothing should be returned.

Restriction
The SELECTs within CTE must have offset/paging implemented for performance reasons.

Update
Num of rows and #of tiles vary by the size of actual data. 65 records/3 tiles in this example is just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the final query (between the commented "select *" commands and the DROP TABLE commands) with this:

```
;With CTE
As
(
    SELECT      [Num]
    FROM        #Temp1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      [Num]
    FROM        #Temp2
)
SELECT      [Num]
FROM        CTE
ORDER BY    [Num] OFFSET ( @TileNumber * @RowsToReturn ) ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowsToReturn ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But the restriction is to include offset logic for each selects within CTE for performance reason.

Comment: Putting the offset logic on each component of the UNION will prevent it from working.  Temp1 contains 49 rows and Temp2 contains 16, but your requirement is to consider them a single set of 65 records.

Comment: That being said, I recall reading in a discussion on generating a list of sequential numbers via cross join calls in a CTE that the WHERE clause on the outside of a CTE is "pushed up" into the CTE by the optimizer.  If I can find that article I'll link to it here.

Comment: Yea, that's the problem. The only reason we have added this restriction is because each one of those selects within CTE can pull millions of rows each time and doing that for each tile/"page" can kill the system. So was asked to find a solution that works. Your sequential number idea sounds interesting and maybe that is the solution to this problem. Yea, please post back if you find it. Thank you

Comment: How many temp tables are you creating, and are they all the same structure, or similar enough that you could create a single temp table?  Or are the temp tables an artifact of your example?

Comment: Currently, there're only 2 temp table in my test query (ready query doesn't select data from temp tables/joins). The schema for both real tables are similar (using NULL for missing fields in either table for Union ALL).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157511/discussion-between-brian-and-007).

Comment: Here's the link to the article that talks about CTE's being intelligent enough to not do unnecessary work:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

It's in the "Stacked CTE" example, a bit over half-way down.